# What happens to an electron which falls into a black hole?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, black-holes, electrons, quantum-gravity

I was thinking about this for a while. The tidal effects due to strong gravitational fields will "spaghettify" something that falls into a black hole. But, electron is a fundamental particle. So, what actually happens to it?

I know only some basics of GR and I haven't studied the subject well enough to examine this question mathematically. But, my feeling is that because we are talking about electron quantum mechanics comes into picture and, thus using general relativity alone wont give the answer. In that case does the proposed theories of quantum gravity like for example, string theory give a solution to this problem?

Comment: An electron is a fundamental 'pointlike' particle. This means that it has no spatial extent and so is not susceptible to being 'spaghettified' due to tidal forces.